# iPhone 3GS + / iPad 1 + maximum hardware audio sample rate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio

Does anyone know what is the maximum sample rate for the Built in mic,  mic input and output for newer devices ( iPhone 3GS and newer, iPad and iPad 2)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) is the default audio format on iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch. AAC has sample rate range of 8 to 96 kHz so should not this be the sample rate for the devices too?

Comment: you may want to go through this link as well - http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9158-audio-sound-frequency.html

Comment: It makes sense to make that assumption. But if the hardware supports only a lower max like 48khz then it could just covert 96khz sampled sac to the current setting. I guess testing it out is the only way to find out. I will do that and post my results if you are interested :)